# Return type "self" in abstract PHP class

Tags: php, inheritance, phpstorm, php-7, late-static-binding

Trying to make an abstract class to partially implement functionality of its' child classes and force a contract upon them required for this implementation, I use the following construct:

```
abstract class Parent {

    public static function fromDB(string $name = '') {
        $instance = new static();
        if (!empty($name)) {
            $instance->setName($name)->read();
        }
        return $instance;
    }

    public abstract function read();

    public abstract function setName(string $name): self;

}
```

Here PHP seems to understand that `setName($name)` returns an Object of type `Parent`, but PhpStorm indicates that `read()` can not be called on the result, which would have been the expected result.

> Error Message: Referenced Method is not found in subject class.

I do not understand why this happens, and even suspect a bug in PHP or PhpStorm.

I've read up on Late static binding and the following questions which partially talk about this problem, but I couldn't figure out how to fix it:

- [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30952876/static-return-type-in-php-7-interfaces)
- [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999066/why-does-php-5-2-disallow-abstract-static-class-methods)
- [Late Static Binding Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

Thank you for your time and help.

I'm trying to implement setName in child classes in a way so it is clear that the type of the returned Object is the one of the child:

```
public function setName(string $name = null): user {...}
```

which doesn't work with `self` return type and `static` is forbidden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code sample looks fine in **PhpStorm 2017.2** (currently in EAP stage) but shows warning in 2017.1.4.

[image]

Quite possibly it was fixed by [WI-33991](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-33991) or one of the related tickets.

---

You may get & try the 2017.2 EAP build at any time from here: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program

It comes with own 30-days license and can run in parallel to your current version (IDE-wide settings are stored in separate folders).

Comment: I opened a ticket and it was closed as a dupe of that one, so it does appear fixed in the next version

Answer (score 7):

`self` will **always** refer to the class its in, **never children classes**. So when `Parent` says to return `:self`, it's expecting you to create a function that returns an instance of `Parent`. What you need to do is have your child class declare that it's doing that directly. Instead of declaring the child's `setName` will return `:self` (which is an instance of `Child`), we declare we're going to return our `Parent` class directly. PHP sees this as perfectly valid (`Child` is an instance of `Parent` after all)

We cannot use `:static` here because `static` is a reserved word in the class definitions

```
abstract class ParentTest {

    public static function fromDB(string $name = '') {
        $instance = new static();
        if (!empty($name)) {
            $instance->setName($name)->read();
        }
        return $instance;
    }

    public abstract function read();

    public abstract function setName(string $name): self;

}

class Child extends ParentTest {
    public function read() {

    }

    public function setName(string $name) :ParentTest {
        return $this;
    }
}

$child = new Child();
```

The above code [runs without error](https://3v4l.org/IYf0Q)

Comment: fixes the following problem of implementation in child class partially - see edit in question - the problem with read() persists

Comment: ok wierdly enough phpstorm still shows the error and its internal server crashes when trying to execute that code, while apache doesn't.
Follow up: how can i still get a child from the method?

Comment: I'm thinking that might be a bug with PHPStorm then (just tested on 2017.1.4 and it does throw a fit despite being valid). This is an edge case and I could easily see them having missed it.

Comment: The `Child` declaration can have `: parent` rather then `: ParentTest` which would make it easier to rename the class later.  (Obviously a similar approach can't be used for a `Grandchild`.)

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, there is an intelligent and SOLID approach to use interfaces.
It is even required for libraries supposed to be used by 3rd-parties.

So, we just set the interface name as a type instead of 'self' in all parent classes and continue using 'self' for children.

```
<?php
interface EntityInterface 
{
    public function setName(string $name): EntityInterface;
}

abstract class ParentTest implements EntityInterface 
{

    public abstract function read();

    public abstract function setName(string $name): EntityInterface;

}

class Child extends ParentTest 
{
    
    private string $name = '';
    
    public function read(): string 
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self 
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
}

$child = new Child();
echo $child->setName('hello')->read();
```

Answer (score -3):

Try change to return **static**, static should indiciating you are returning the extending class, which may remove the error.

This is guess work but it's worth a shot.

```
public abstract function setName(string $name): static;
```

EDIT: Ok i dont think that will do, can you provide more information on the question? What is the purpose of read? fromDb? etc?

Comment: Ok i dont think that will do, can you provide more information on the question? What is the purpose of read? fromDb? etc?

Comment: Just FYI, trying to declare `:static` as your return type throws a `E_FATAL`

Comment: Manyt hanks, realised this so hoping for more info on what Simon is trying to achieve so we can look at redesign. @Simon can you provide details of what you are trying to achieve, i think this class can be refactored.

Comment: ok so the Parent Class is a representation of a general object in a CMS.
It provides dataloading capabilities from Database (fromDB($pk)) , from arrays or from json; setName is baysicalls the setter for the identifying value. read just takes the classes current parameters and tries to fill it with values from database, hence its call by fromDB;
It also provides abstract implementations for a few magic methods.

Comment: Does set name need to be an abstract method? Does its implementation differ per subclass?

Comment: yes, sadly yes one class represents a user which holds some limitations, since there is a login mechanism

Comment: to be more precise - its implementation accesses a field named "name" which not all classes have...