# PhpStorm not finding methods in objects created by late static binding by parent abstract class

Tags: php, phpstorm, php-7.1, phpstorm-2017.1

In my PHP application I have a base class for all database objects, which is further extended by specific model classes. It goes on like this (simplified):

```
abstract class Model extends Collection {

    (...)

    function __construct(string $primary_key, string $value) {
        $data = MysqlDB::instance() -> select(static::TABLE, implode(',', static::COLUMNS), "$primary_key=\"$value\"");
        if (count($data) != 1)
            throw new ModelException('Select condition uncertain');
        parent::__construct($data[0]);
    }

    public static function getById(string $id) : ?Model {
        try {
            return new static('id', $id);
        } catch (ModelException $e) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    (...)

}
```

The point is, I use the `getById` function on child classes to obtain the needed objects. However, since the return type of `getById` method is `Model`, PhpStorm can't figure out what methods the objects has and highlights the ones I use as an error. Consequently, no type-hinting available.

For instance, assuming that `final class User extends Model` and that class `User` has method `sendNotification`, this kind of code:

```
User::getById($id) -> sendNotification($param1, $param2, ...)
```

has `sendNotification` yellowed out as though it did not exist.

I know this isn't that much of an issue, but it's really irritating in terms of that I get distracted by constant redundant warnings and that I can't use type-hinting in such a usage case.

Comment: **1)** Try with actual PHPDoc for your `getById()` where you specify dynamic type (e.g.`@return static` or `@return $this`) **2)** Kind of the same .. but using PHP 7.1 functionality -- try using `self` as return type instead of `Model` (I mean here: `...getById(string $id) : ?Model`). But for this one you should use **2017.2 EAP** build as 2017.1 has issues with that (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44806801/783119)

Comment: Thanks, `@return static` worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with actual PHPDoc for your `getById()` where you specify dynamic type (e.g. `@return static` or `@return $this`).

That's the most common way of providing such "this class and its' children" typehint.

---

Another possible option is kind of the same .. but using PHP 7.1 functionality (so no PHPDoc blocks).

Try using `self` as return type instead of `Model`. I mean here:

```
public static function getById(string $id) : ?Model {
```

use this instead:

```
public static function getById(string $id) : ?self {
```

But for this one you should use PhpStorm **2017.2 EAP build** as 2017.1.x has issues with that (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44806801/783119 as an example).

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to achieve this, none of them has anything to do with PHPStorm.

First overwrite the method in every child with the proper return type:

```
/**
 * @return User
 */
public static function getById(string $id) : ?Model { return parent::getById($id); }
```

Second add all possible children to the return tag of the abstract class.

```
/**
 * @return Model|User|...
 */
public static function getById(string $id) : ?Model { /* ... */ }
```

Third add a type hint just in place:

```
/** @var User $user */
$user = User::getById($id);
$user->sendNotification($param1, $param2, ...);
```

These are not nice and hard to maintain. But there is no "setting" in PHPStorm for that.

Comment: I would not consider #1 and #2 as possible options. I mean -- yes, it will do ... but it's ugly and extra job for no reason.

Comment: That's what I said. I am not recommending any of them, but they are workarounds for the proposed problem.

Comment: Sure. I just have some other ideas in mind -- see my comment below the actual question -- that may work (don't have 7.1 and such code to test .. but in theory it should work).