# Laravel : Get main level category on a tree parent child relationship

Tags: laravel, nested, treeview, parent-child, eloquent-relationship

I have a multi level Category model , each Category can have childs and parent on the same table (tree structure) on the same sql table.

```
public function childs(){
return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
}

public function parent(){
return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent_id');
}

+---------+---------+------------+
| id      |cat_name | parent_id  | 
+---------+---------+------------+
|       1 |     A   | NULL       |
|       2 |     B   | NULL       |
|       3 |     AA  | 1          |
|       4 |     BB  | 2          |
|       5 |     AAA | 4          |
+---------+---------+------------+
```

From my controller i want to get all categories with their main category (not the parent category) like so :

```
 $categories= Category::with('mainCategory')->get();
```

The desired result

```
id: 1
cat_name: A
parent_id:null
mainCategory:{}

id: 2
cat_name: B
parent_id:null
mainCategory:{}

id: 3
cat_name: AA
parent_id:1
mainCategory:{
             id: 1
             cat_name: A
             parent_id:NULL
             }

id: 4
cat_name: BB
parent_id:2
mainCategory:{
             id: 2
             cat_name: B
             parent_id:NULL
             }


id: 5
cat_name: AAA
parent_id:3
mainCategory:{
             id: 1
             cat_name: AAA
             parent_id:NULL
             }
```

For exemple : category AAA with id 5 ->   mainCat is  A

I need a model function that return categories and  mainCategory for each one, so i can apply the function from another controller rather than CategoryController.

Comment: Create two tables for parent-category and child-category, you can easily using hasMany

Comment: thanks for response, but i think you didn't get the question well.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question.

create two tables for parent and child, because parent category has many child category

Example tables

Tabel parent categories

`id, name`

Table child categories

`id, parent_category_id`

And create two model too

`ParentCategoryModel`

```
public function childs(){ return $this->hasMany(ChildCategoryModel::class, 'parent_category_id', 'id'); }
```

`ChildCategoryModel`

```
public function parent(){ return $this->belongsTo(ParentCategoryModel::class,'parent_category_id')->withDefault(); }
```

Inside your controller, you can use eloquent like this
`categories=ChildCategoryModel::with('parent')->get();`

Comment: thanks Encang but you don't need two tables for that, one table with a foreign Id can give the same result, beside, i don't have any problem getting childs, what i want is to get recursively the top level parent of an N level child.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the **root parent** category, which is a category that has the given category as a direct or indirect child and has no parent category itself. The root parent of a category that has no parent category is this category itself.

All you need to get the root parent is to recursively traverse the parents and their parents until you stumble upon a parent that has no parent, which is the root parent that we need to find.

To do this in Eloquent, adding the following method to Category model will be sufficient:

```
/**
* Retrieve the root parent of the current category.
* The root parent of a category that has no parent is that category itself.
*
* @return \App\Models\Category
*/
public function rootParent(): static
{
    return $this->parent ? $this->parent->rootParent() : $this;
}
```

Please note that static return types [were introduced in PHP 8](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/static_return_type). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30952876/) covers more details.